# Skill Matrix with various Technology

Tags: team-management, project-management-style, skills

I am creating a skill matrix for my team in a excel sheet. My team consists of Developers & Testers.

I've included Technologies (like Phyton, cobol etc), Testing, Tools (jira) & Methodology (Agile) and asked my team to provide rating against their name from 1 to 3 (1=no knowledge;2=intermediate;3=Expert). I am also planning to take overall score at the end.

Question:
A developer maybe not require to complete testing skills right likewise a tester maybe not required to have computer language skills. How shall I calculate average & overall skill score due to gap in skills based on role?

**Update:**
Definitely, this is not a homework assignment :-) I am working as a PM and want to create a skill matrix so I could prepare & build required skills for my team as we're about to start on a new project.

If someone rate him/her as 4 in any of skill, he/she may train others. Team had provided me data with their rank. I want to understand how to visualize & reveal weakness or strength.

Are there any standard practice? Does it make any sense now?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with such scoring system? The rationale behind it might hide a deeper question.

Comment: This smells like a homework assignment. What has the *instructor* told you to do, what context has been provided, and what has the course material indicated is the "correct" answer from the instructor's point of view?

Comment: This question seems on topic, but lacks sufficient context or clear intent to provide the opportunity for a canonical answer. I'm closing it until the OP responds to the requests for additional information and context, at which time it can be re-opened by the community if it seems on topic and in line with our help center guidelines.

Comment: Definitely, this is not a homework assignment :-) I am working as a PM and want to create a skill matrix so I could prepare & build required skills for my team as we're about to start on a new project.

If someone rate him/her as 4 in any of skill, he/she may train others. Team had provided me data with their rank. I want to understand how to visualize & reveal weakness or strength.

Are there any standard practice? Does it make any sense now?

Answer (score 2):

What is the value of an overall score? Why degrade a person's skill score by averaging other lower or non-existent skill scores that have little to no bearing on that person's tasks. What value does an overall, and apparently averaged, score provides?

Let's use pilots as an example. One pilot is scored flying fixed-wing because he's rated in fixed-wing and another in rotary-wing because that is her rating. What does it tell us if we lowered their skill rating vis-a-vis a mean average in their respective aircraft due to their non-existent skill, and rating, in the other aircraft?

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you are trying to measure and why. A weighted average score might be appropriate, with different weightings associated with the different skills.

In technical teams it's very difficult to categorise and measure the relevant capabilities of individuals in this way. That's one reason why cross-functional and self-organising teams of generalising specialists tend to be preferred over specialist individuals or teams.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Could you help me out with appropriate example on how to use weighted avg score with an example?